# Spatie Crawler: Some links always return 503 Error on production

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler

I run a crawler on my website and there are some links from Amazon that always return 503 code on production, but they return 200 in my local machine. Does anyone have any ideas on this issue? Is the problem from my server IP or something?

Some links:

```
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00SZB0BXC
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01BFKIJ06
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005H8C4ZE
```

Here is the code of crawler

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected static array $clientOptions = [
    RequestOptions::COOKIES         => true,
    RequestOptions::CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    RequestOptions::TIMEOUT         => 10,
    RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS => true,
    RequestOptions::HEADERS         => [
        'User-Agent' => '*',
    ],
];


Crawler::create(static::$clientOptions)
            ->setCrawlProfile(new CustomProfile($this->website))
            ->setCrawlObserver(new LinkCrawler($this->website))
            ->setParseableMimeTypes(['text/html', 'text/plain'])
            ->setMaximumResponseSize(1024 * 1024 * 3)
            ->startCrawling($this->website->url);
```

Comment: It's possible that Amazon has measures in place to block certain types of traffic.  Have you tried providing a user agent that makes the request appear to be from a browser, rather than just `*`?

Comment: Can you give me some example of agent? Thank you!

Comment: Chrome, for example:  `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36`

Comment: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/

Comment: I did try: `wget -U "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36" https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MH37484`. But still get 503 :(

Comment: When I run your command, I get a 200 response:  `--2020-08-09 08:04:52--  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00MH37484
Resolving www.amazon.com (www.amazon.com)... 99.84.218.165
Connecting to www.amazon.com (www.amazon.com)|99.84.218.165|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK`

Comment: Seem like it blocked my IP.